# Re-rendering a cached Node in JavaFX at higher resolution

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to render a **lot** of nodes (millions) in JavaFX inside a container node and I'm coming up against performance issues when I translate or scale the container node.  I discovered that I can do `containerNode.setCache(true)`, which results in smooth translation and scaling, but then of course, node looks very grainy when you zoom in.

I'm trying to find some way to use the grainy cached version when scaling/zooming, and then I want to programmatically re-render the node at a higher resolution once I'm zoomed in.  Or at least re-render the visible portion.

I can't figure out how to instruct the cache to re-render the node.  I did notice some interesting behavior in my experiments:

1. If you first display the node with cache off and you're very zoomed out (the node appears small) and then activate the cache, zooming in will result in very a very grainy appearance.
2. However, if you (again) first display the node with cache off but you're very zoomed in, activating the cache will result in a much higher resolution cached render.  It looks like it chooses the cache resolution based on zoom at the time the cache was activated.
3. **BUT** (to my disappointment), if you created a cache while zoomed out (like in step 1) and then zoomed in, deactivating then reactivating the cache does not result in a new cache render.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do additionally to enabling the caching is to play with the cache hints. For example before you start zooming you set the cache hint SPEED and keep that during the zoom operation. Once you are done with zooming you switch back to QUALITY which should cause a re-rendering. The idea is that during zooming only the cached image is scaled and once you have reached the final size you re-render the nodes in high quality according to their current size.

Comment: That worked, although it did require some experimentation.  Switching from SPEED -> QUALITY -> SPEED immeditately in the code didn't work.  I had to let the UI do it's thing and then switch back to SPEED later.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it works for you although my intention was to use it in the opposite order. The standard mode would be QUALITY and when you start a zoom you switch to SPEED and after you are done with the zoom you switch back to QUALITY. So the order of operation would be QUALITY -> SPEED -> QUALITY.